# Animated slider - animating content after background fade

Tags: jquery, css, slider, jquery-animate, delay

I'm attempting to build a slider that fades through background colours and after that background has faded in, the content animates in a few seconds later.

I've tried adding the .delay() to animate things in but that seems to time itself from the page load rather than from that particular slide becoming visible.

Hope that makes sense, any help will be much appreciated.

Here is an example of where i'm at so far - http://robsarna.co.uk/stuff/slider/

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Basic jQuery Slider - Demo</title>

<!-- bjqs.css contains the *essential* css needed for the slider to work -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.robsarna.co.uk/stuff/bjqs.css">





<!-- load jQuery and the plugin -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.robsarna.co.uk/stuff/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  .open {font-size:30px;}
  #slide1 {background-color:#09F; color:white; font-size:50px;}
  .big1 {height:1000px!important; background-color:#09F;}
  #slide2 {background-color:#C33; color:white; font-size:50px;}
  .big2 {height:1000px!important; background-color:#C33}
   #slide3 {background-color:#3F6; color:white; font-size:50px;}
  .big3 {height:1000px!important; background-color:#3F6;}

  /* Basic jQuery Slider essential styles */

ul.bjqs{position:relative; list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden; display:none;}
li.bjqs-slide{position:absolute; display:none;}
ul.bjqs-controls{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:9999;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{position:absolute;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a{right:0;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a{left:0;}
ol.bjqs-markers{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;}
ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered{text-align: center;}
ol.bjqs-markers li{display:inline;}
ol.bjqs-markers li a{display:inline-block;}
p.bjqs-caption{display:block;width:96%;margin:0;padding:2%;position:absolute;bottom:0;}



  </style>

</head>

 <body>

<div id="container">



  <h2>Slide Example</h2>


  <div id="banner-slide">

    <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
    <ul class="bjqs">
      <li id="slide1"><a href="#" id="open1" class="open">OPEN1</a>
      <div id="content1"> CONTENT TO ANIMATE 1</div>
      </li>



 <li id="slide2"><a href="#" id="open2" class="open">OPEN2</a>  <div id="content2"> CONTENTTO ANIMATE 2</div></li>
      <li id="slide3"><a href="#" id="open3" class="open">OPEN3</a>  <div id="content3"> CONTENT TO ANIMATE 3</div></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

  </div>
  <!-- End outer wrapper -->


  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {



      $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype      : 'fade',
        height        : 320,
        width         : 620,
        responsive    : true,
        randomstart   : false
      });


      $('#open1').click(function(){

    $('#banner-slide').toggleClass('big1');


    });

 $('#open2').click(function(){

    $('#banner-slide').toggleClass('big2');


    });


 $('#open3').click(function(){

    $('#banner-slide').toggleClass('big3');



    });

     });
     </script>

   </div>



   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Please show your code so we can help you fix it, you are able to set a handler function to execute once a callback is finished.

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to jquery, the code is on the example above... sorry to be a pain, just not sure how else to upload the code!

Comment: Copy and paste the code into your question by doing an Edit. You can then wrap it in code tags by highlighting it and pressing the `{}` button at the top of the editor.

Comment: you want to have a look at using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

Comment: Pasted in the code, thanks for your help.